# How to get the status of the App switcher during screen sharing with ReplayKit

Tags: ios, swift, replaykit

I would like to execute a certain process only when an iOS screen sharer is using the App switcher during screen sharing.

Is there a way to get the status of the App switcher (if it's active or not) during screen sharing with ReplayKit? And if so, what iOS API or method should I use?